# How to apply a djngoFilterBackend in a detail_route() viewset

Tags: django

I want to use django filters in a view which has some other behaviour, without returning viewset retrieve or list methods.
My code is the following:

```
class ArticleView(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = get_serializer_class(Article)
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('TYPE',)

    @detail_route()
    def articles(self, request, pk=None):
        some_behaviour()
        return MY QUERYSET (which can or cannot be modified) FILTERED
```

so by hitting `/api/articles` and its derivates the queryset gets filtered correctly, also if i return self.retrieve(request) (obviously), but i am not able to modify my queryset. Then my question is, what is needed to apply django filters EXPLICITLY in that situation, or how can i tell him to do that instead of doing r`equest.query_string.pop(bla bla bla)`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently got similar problem.

I've found `ViewSet.filter_queryset()` function that is doing exactly that.

Remember that `ViewSet.get_object()` also use `self.filer_queryset()` so make Your `detailed_route` method usinq `get_object_by_pk()` like:

```
class ViewSet:
    def get_object_by_pk(self, pk):
        return self.get_queryset().get(pk=pk)

    @detail_route():
    def something(self, request, pk):
        object = self.get_object_by_pk(pk)
        queryset = object.whatevet_set
        page = self.paginate_queryset(self.filter_queryset(queryset))

        if page is not None:
            serializer = SerializerClass(page, many=True, context={'request': request})
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = SerializerClass(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```